# ロードされている.NETアセンブリの一覧を取得する

Tags: visual-studio, .net

Windows10にて。
実行中の特定のプロセスが使用している、またはプロセスにかかわらず
現在使用されている.NETアセンブリ(DLL)のPathないし名称の一覧を
取得する簡単な方法があればご教授いただきたい。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

他プロセスの`AppDomain`に読み込まれているマネージアセンブリーの一覧を得たいのであれば`sos.dll`などのデバッガーの技法が必要になるのではないかと思います。

しかしネイティブモジュールの場合は`tasklist.exe /m`や[Process Status API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684894.aspx)で検索可能です。これらの出力にはNgenでネイティブイメージが生成されているマネージアセンブリーも含まれますので、`mscorlib.ni.dll`のような既知の標準アセンブリーを検索したいのであればこの方法で十分だと思います。